# particular solution of a linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So far as I have known, terms without parameter is particular solution and terms with parameter is general solution.

Then the differential equation below can be solved with variation parameters...

x<sup>2</sup>y<sup>''</sup> -3xy<sup>'</sup>$ + 4y =$ x<sup>2</sup>lnxe

$x >0$, y<sub>1</sub>(x) = x<sup>2</sup>, y<sub>2</sub>(x) = x<sup>2</sup>lnx

The solution of this equation is $y =$ $\frac{1}6x^2(lnx)^3 + \frac{1}2x^2(lnx)^2 +c_1x^2lnx + c_2x^2$

Thus, I conclude that $y_p = \frac{1}6x^2(lnx)^3 + \frac{1}2x^2(lnx)^2$ which is part particular solution.

However, according to my professor, particular solution is $y_p = \frac{1}6x^2(lnx)^3$ which excludes $\frac{1}2x^2(lnx)^2$

I'm quite confused that why particular solution dosen't include $\frac{1}2x^2(lnx)^2$

Did my professor make a mistake or any part that I'm missing right now?

Comment: Your answer corresponds to the right-hand side $x^2 \ln(xe)$, whereas your professor's corresponds to just $x^2 \ln(x)$. Could there be some typo or mis-copying somewhere? I think the best thing would be to ask your professor! (By the way, it would be much easier to read your post if you used [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).)